# When should we use core in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one question, if I use core, I just write some functions to my MY_Model to reuse that functions when I need. Is it the only thing MY_Model can do? Anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Core** to hack with pre-built functionalities.
Like you want to tweak the default garbage collector of sessions.
Basically, the core contains the code which makes CodeIgniter to work and contain default-features provided in CodeIgniter.

> **Model** is what you are you are adding for your application. The Model for your app.

Refer [MVC concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)